# Tweets streaming: How to set tweets number limit?

Tags: python, twitter

I used a python script to stream tweets and store them in a Mongodb database using tweepy. Everything was working just fine, but when I tried to set a limit for the number of tweets, tweets are no longer retrieved, I can't see the error, could you please help?

`class MyListener(StreamListener):`

```
  def __init__(self, num_tweets, max_tweets=60):
        self.numTweets = num_tweets
        self.limit = max_tweets

def on_data(self, data):
    print("tweet")
     while self.numTweets < self.limit:
        #self.numTweets+=1
        try:
            client = MongoClient()
            db = client['twitter1_db']
            collection = db['twitter1_collection']
            tweet = json.loads(data)
            collection.insert_one(tweet)
            print(tweet)
            self.numTweets= self.numTweets+ 1
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)`
```

`twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener(num_tweets, max_tweets))
twitter_stream.filter(track=Keywords_list)`